# Number of dimensions allowed in GA4 data API

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

While going through the new GA4 data API documentation, I didn't come across any specification for the number of dimensions allowed in a single request.
It seemed like there was no upper limit. This [document](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/basics#dimensions) doesn’t mention an upper limit and states the following:
“In a report request, you can specify zero or more dimensions.”

However when I try executing the v1alpha:runReport API via postman I get this response if I give more than 8 dimensions:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Requests are limited to 8 dimensions within a nested request.\n  This request is for 9 dimensions.",
        "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
    }
}
```

Has the number of dimensions allowed in a request been reduced to 8? If yes, can you point me to some document that states this?
The earlier UA batchGet API used to allow max 9 dimensions and I was expecting the same limit with the new GA4 data API.

Steps to Reproduce:
Post a request to  v1alpha:runReport with more than 8 dimensions:

Request URL: https://analyticsdata.googleapis.com/v1alpha:runReport

Request Auth: A valid bearer token

Request Body:

```
{
"entity":{
    "propertyId":"123456789"
},
"dateRanges":[
    {
        "startDate":"2021-03-29",
        "endDate":"2021-03-29"
    }
],
"dimensions":[
    {
        "name":"eventName"
    },
    {
        "name":"source"
    },
    {
        "name":"medium"
    },
    {
        "name":"hostname"
    },
    {
        "name":"dateHour"
    },
    {
        "name":"deviceCategory"
    },
    {
        "name":"browser"
    },
    {
        "name":"city"
    },
    {
        "name":"country"
    }
],
"metrics":[
    {
        "name":"screenPageViews"
    },
    {
        "name":"userEngagementDuration"
    },
    {
        "name":"eventCount"
    }
]
```

}

Comment: please edit your question and include [example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Google analytics [GA4 data api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/basics#dimensions) is a brand new api, released as part of GA4.  As such it has not been reduced to 8 dimensions this is the current limit as it stands

> Requests are limited to 8 dimensions within a nested request.

The Google analytics reporting api may allow for additional dimensions and metrics but they are it's a completely different system. You can't compare universal analytics and GA4

Note: i have submitted a note about the lack of documentation to the team

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. An addition to the documentation will surely help.

Comment: Its either still in alpha or beta,  so things are still stabilizing.

Comment: Heard back from Google its mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1alpha/Dimension) they agree that it would make sense to mention it on the other page as well.   Well spotted thanks

Comment: Great! Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 1):

Updated docs state up to 9 dimensions are now allowed.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/basics#dimensions

Answer (score 1):

Looks like its updated to 10:
google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 Requests are limited to 10 metrics within a nested request.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).